# Convert a "normal" rectangle to a set of GLes vectors?

Tags: c, opengl-es, geometry

How would I convert a "normal" rectangle into a set of **OpenGL ES** vertices. I'm not good at geometry so I have no idea how vertices work, and I want to be able to manipulate rectangles without having to work out the values for the vertices by trial and error.

I basically need to convert this structure:

```
typedef struct __nrect {
    float width;
    float height;
    float depth;

    /* center */
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} simple3dRect;
```

To something like this:

```
    const GLfloat cubeVertices[6][12] = {
    { 1,-1, 1, -1,-1, 1,  1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1 },
    { 1, 1, 1,  1,-1, 1,  1, 1,-1,  1,-1,-1 },
    {-1, 1,-1, -1,-1,-1, -1, 1, 1, -1,-1, 1 },
    { 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1,  1, 1,-1, -1, 1,-1 },
    { 1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,  1, 1,-1, -1, 1,-1 },
    { 1,-1, 1, -1,-1, 1,  1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1 },
};
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: The normalRect structure doesn't have enough information to do this - is it centred around (0,0,0)? Does it range from (0,0,0) - (width,height, depth)?

Comment: Your normalRect looks like a volume and not a rectangle to me. Think about how many faces a cube has and how many vertices define a face, now check how you get to each face from the information given in your normalRect (assuming that this is all you have as it wont allow for much).

Comment: A cube has 8 vertices, each with 3 components.  I have no idea why your array ended up with 3 times as many entries as necessary (actually, yes I do, each vertex is used in three faces.  But it still shouldn't be organized as 6x12).  If you make a 3x6 matrix of vertices, you can use a matrix multiply to rotate, scale and translate it anywhere you want.  And then use `glDrawElements` to render.

Comment: I also suggest you rename it to something not using the word "normal" which is confusing as it does not contain normal vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the resulting cube is axis-aligned and that width corresponds to the x-axis, height to the y-axis and depth to the z-axis:

```
const GLfloat cubeVertices[6][12] = {
    { x + width/2, y - height/2, z + depth/2,  x - width/2, y - height/2, z + depth/2,  x + width/2, y + height/2, z + depth/2,  x - width/2, y + height/2, z + depth/2 },
    { x + width/2, y + height/2, z + depth/2,  x + width/2, y - height/2, z + depth/2,  x + width/2, y + height/2, z - depth/2,  x + width/2, y - height/2, z - depth/2 },
    { x - width/2, y + height/2, z - depth/2,  x + width/2, y - height/2, z - depth/2,  x - width/2, y + height/2, z + depth/2,  x - width/2, y - height/2, z + depth/2 },
    { x + width/2, y + height/2, z + depth/2,  x - width/2, y + height/2, z + depth/2,  x + width/2, y + height/2, z - depth/2,  x - width/2, y + height/2, z - depth/2 },
    { x + width/2, y - height/2, z - depth/2,  x - width/2, y - height/2, z - depth/2,  x + width/2, y + height/2, z - depth/2,  x - width/2, y + height/2, z - depth/2 },
    { x + width/2, y - height/2, z + depth/2,  x - width/2, y - height/2, z + depth/2,  x + width/2, y - height/2, z - depth/2,  x - width/2, y - height/2, z - depth/2 },
};
```

Clearly, this can be simplified/optimised by pre-computing the width/2, etc. values, longhand included here for clarity.

Comment: Won't this give a cube with twice the width, height and depth? I think it should be `width/2` and so on.

Comment: I think any compiler these days will optimize away the redundant {width,height,depth}/2 into a precomputation. This is just too easy to implement on the AST.