# Get rectangle vertices by center, normal, length and height

Tags: c++, math, graphics, geometry

I am looking for a way to get all the vertices of a rectangle whose center, normal, length and height I know. I am a little weak in maths so please help me. 
Edit : the plane is in 3D space.

Comment: "center, normal, length and height" are not enough in 3D. Suppose I tell you "origin, z-axis, 2 units, 1 unit". Now *any* 2-by-1 rectangle, centred on the origin, and lying in the xy plane, meets these criteria.

Comment: Similar question, except it seems the OP only wants one of the sides: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503871/convert-a-normal-rectangle-to-a-set-of-gles-vectors

Answer (score 1):

You can easily calculate the x and y coordinates of the vertices of a rectangle in 2D space given the center, width and height by subtracting/adding half the width/height from the x/y position of the center point.

If you need this in 3D space, this becomes a little more tricky and relies on a bit of trigonometry, but still follows the same principle. You'll need one extra piece of information. You need some way of fixing the orientation of the square in some direction; ie, which direction is the rectangle 'facing'. The normal will allow you to work out what plane the rectangle is on, but without some orientation on that plane, the best you can do is work out a set of possible values in a circle around the center for each of the vertices.

Comment: This will only work if the rectangle is axis aligned, I don't think this is the case here since OP mentions a "normal".

Comment: @user786653: Yes, you are right, and I specifically said the math above is for 2-space only. To fix the points in 3-space then you need more than the normal, you need some way to fixing the orientation as well otherwise there's no way to pin down where any of the points are, just a circle of possible points in a circle around the center on a plane given by the normal.

Comment: What I meant was that the OP is probably looking for something like (assuming a 2d vector class): `topleft = center + normal * vec2(-width/2,0) + vec2(-normal.y, normal.x) * vec2(-height/2,0)` though of course I can't be sure what is meant.

Comment: @YAHOO Then unfortunately, you need more information than you have available to get a solid answer.

Comment: @YAHOO Unless you have the width and/or height as vectors (ie. you have a direction as well as a distance). Then you are in luck.

Comment: what i am doing is something like this....
 
leftPoint = midpoint + normal.cross( Vector3(0,-1,0) * width ) + norm.cross( Vector3(1,0,0) * height ) 

rightPoint = midpoint - normal.cross( Vector3(0,-1,0) * width ) + norm.cross( Vector3(1,0,0) * height ) 

but the problem is the x values of the corners are  all right but y values of corners are varied as the normal vary....

Comment: @YAHOOOOO: Unfortunately, that's the issue. Unless you can make some assumptions about the orientation and/or one of the dimensions and rule it out (ie, you have your rectangle axis aligned as user786653 suggested) then this is an impossible problem. You just don't have enough information on hand to be able to calculate what you are looking for.